# How to save a plot occupying the whole page of a PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, figure

I want to create a **multi-page PDF file for printing** using python. I would prefer to do this with a library that could work well in any environment so I tried with **matplotlib**.

I can produce the desired figure of A4 size, and create a multi-page PDF file, but **the figure artist shrinks and does not occupy the whole page**.

I can either produce a PDF of A4-sized pages with padding around the figure, or a PDF file with smaller page size (the page shrinks around the figure to remove the padding, with the figure remaining the same size).

Can someone help?

(I don't think this is duplicated, there are other questoions about the padding but not with the same aim as I have and I could not see any answer that worked for me - I have been searching around for days!)

What I have tried so far following a few SO questions/answers is:

- Using `bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0` in the `pyplot.savefig()` function, which gives a smaller than A4 PDF page with no padding.

(Strangely, this works well with EPS format, which prints straight into real size in A4 paper, but I don't know how to do a multi-page file out of that.)

- If I do not use `bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0`, the figure size seems more or less the same but the padding around fills the space to make an A4 page.
- Using `fig.tight_layout(rect=[0,0,1,1])` or `fig.tight_layout(pad=0)`, which keeps the padding.

This example code produces the figure in EPS (A4 no padding), PDF (A4 with padding) and TIFF (no padding but smaller size, so when you print it has padding):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

def plot_form_page():
    # A4 canvas
    fig_width_cm = 21                                # A4 page
    fig_height_cm = 29.7
    inches_per_cm = 1 / 2.54                         # Convert cm to inches
    fig_width = fig_width_cm * inches_per_cm         # width in inches
    fig_height = fig_height_cm * inches_per_cm       # height in inches
    fig_size = [fig_width, fig_height]

    plt.rc('text', usetex=False) # so that LaTeX is not needed when creating a PDF with PdfPages later on
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(fig_size)
    fig.set_facecolor('#9999ff')

    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(29, 21, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)    

    # external axis
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, :])
    # for side in ["top", "bottom", "left", "right"]:
    #     ax0.spines[side].set_visible(False)

    # header
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4, 1:4])
    ax1.set_facecolor('#bbffbb')

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4, 4:-6])
    ax2.set_facecolor('#ffbbff')

    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4, -6:-1])
    ax3.set_facecolor('#00bbff')

    # form
    ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7   = [fig.add_subplot(gs[ 5+(i*6):10+(i*6), 1:10]) for i in range(4)]    
    [ax8, ax9, ax10, ax11] = [fig.add_subplot(gs[ 5+(i*6):10+(i*6), 11:20]) for i in range(4)]
    axes = [ax4, ax8, ax5, ax9, ax6, ax10, ax7, ax11]
    for ax in axes:
        ax.set_facecolor('#bbbbbb')

    for ax in fig.axes:
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

    print(fig.properties()['figwidth'], fig.properties()['figheight'])

    # from previous tests:
    #fig.tight_layout(pad=0)

plot_form_page()

plt.savefig('page.tiff',
            dpi=300,
            orientation='portrait',
            box_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.savefig('page.pdf',
            dpi=300,
            orientation='portrait',
            bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.savefig('page.eps',
            dpi=300,
            orientation='portrait',
            papertype='a4',
            bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

fig.properties() give me the right size for A4 in inches:

```py
fig.properties()['figwidth']
fig.properties()['figheight']
```

8.26771653543307 11.69291338582677

But the figure shrinks to allow padding when it comes to printing

You can see the effects in the PDF file here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/naqy9vj4ht6g2mv/Screenshot%202019-04-16%20at%2011.46.48.png?dl=0

With EPS is less of a problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/umycd8ofwod3nk5/Screenshot%202019-04-16%20at%2012.05.52.png?dl=0

(but again, I don't know how to create a multi-page EPS)

With the TIFF file I get the same:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eid1zstbm954121/Screenshot%202019-04-16%20at%2012.11.59.png?dl=0

And this is not necessarily because the printing software adds the padding - the figure now is actually smaller, as it is 1929 × 2655 pixels at 300dpi, this makes it 6.43 × 8.85 in - certainly smaller than A4.

EDIT: This, of course, can be solved by printing with the option 'fit the page' but this could work with any image that has the *proportions* of an A4, I want to have control over the size, if that is possible.

Comment: If you want to define the size of the figure, you cannot use `bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0`, because that effectively changes the figure size. So can you remove this and reformulate the question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ImportanceOfBeingErnest
If I save without the ```bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0``` options, the figure *on the page* is the same size (at least approximately, it might be that the artist changes a bit around the axes), just with added padding so that it fits the A4 page. I have clarified it in the text though.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem. If not using `bbox_inches` when saving, the figure will be exactly A4 in size. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it is confusing - I am not sure if I understand it well myself - and that is why I cannot find a solution. You are right, the figure you produce is exactly A4 in size, *while you are in matplotlib*, but when it becomes a PDF file (also with TIFF, mind), it is reduced, whether you use ```bbox_inches``` or not. The difference is whether the PDF document page will be an A4 with padding around the figure (without ```bbox_inches```) or smaller (with ```bbox_inches='tight'```), with no padding. But the figure artist border never reaches the edge of the PDF page as A4.

Comment: I removed `box_inches='tight', pad_inches=0` from your code and ran it. I opened the resulting pdf in a pdf viewer and clicked on "properties". The page size reported is 8.27 x 11.69 inches, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I *think* I am starting to see what happens:
If I save it without ```bbox_inches``` and with ```facecolor = '#9999ff'```, it looks like this:
 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7uzxiv63ucfsga/Screenshot%202019-04-16%20at%2016.28.36.png?dl=0

So it looks like the artist really reaches the border of the page, but then the internal padding between the subplots and the figure is expanded. How can I reduce that space so the subplots stretch ```'tight'``` to the border of the page (tried ```fig.tight_layout(pad=0)```, didn't work)?

Comment: Ok, I found a way to do what I want - I just don't understand well why. If I add ```gs.tight_layout(fig)``` to my function, the padding between the figure artist and the grid is minimal (like in the EPS save when ```savefig``` includes ```papertype='A4'```) and the page has A4 dimensions.
Got it from https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html. Thanks a lot, I wouldn't have figured out without your suggestion. Can I vote up on a comment? (first question, SO newbie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, and a bit of trial and error, I found a solution that creates an A4-shaped figure that when is saved as an A4 PDF page, it occupies the whole page (not 100% true, there is a very small margin, but it serves the purpose).

It just required to add `gs.tight_layout(fig, pad=0)`. I do not fully understand why, but I suspect that when I was trying to eliminate the padding of the `figure` object (with `plt.savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)` or `fig.tight_layout(...)`), the figure might reach the border of the A4 page, but the `GridSpec` would not, so the padding I was seeing was between the boundaries of the `GridSpec` and the `figure`, not with the border of the paper. When the padding between `GridSpec` and `figure` is set to 0, and the `figure` has A4 size, things seem to work as I wanted.

(I still do not understand why in some cases the page of the PDF file would shrink in size but I am going to leave it here).

This is the code that does what I want, if you create the PDF file, open, and examine the properties, the size is A4, with the rectangles close to the border. WIth the other options, there was either a wide margin or a smaller page size.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

def plot_form_page():
    # A4 canvas
    fig_width_cm = 21                                # A4 page
    fig_height_cm = 29.7
    inches_per_cm = 1 / 2.54                         # Convert cm to inches
    fig_width = fig_width_cm * inches_per_cm         # width in inches
    fig_height = fig_height_cm * inches_per_cm       # height in inches
    fig_size = [fig_width, fig_height]

    plt.rc('text', usetex=False) # so that LaTeX is not needed when creating a PDF with PdfPages later on
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(fig_size)
    fig.set_facecolor('#9999ff')

    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(29, 21, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)    

    # external axis
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, :])
    # for side in ["top", "bottom", "left", "right"]:
    #     ax0.spines[side].set_visible(False)

    # header
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4, 1:4])
    ax1.set_facecolor('#bbffbb')

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4, 4:-6])
    ax2.set_facecolor('#ffbbff')

    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4, -6:-1])
    ax3.set_facecolor('#00bbff')

    # form
    ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7   = [fig.add_subplot(gs[ 5+(i*6):10+(i*6), 1:10]) for i in range(4)]    
    [ax8, ax9, ax10, ax11] = [fig.add_subplot(gs[ 5+(i*6):10+(i*6), 11:20]) for i in range(4)]
    axes = [ax4, ax8, ax5, ax9, ax6, ax10, ax7, ax11]
    for ax in axes:
        ax.set_facecolor('#bbbbbb')

    for ax in fig.axes:
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

    #print(fig.properties()['figwidth'], fig.properties()['figheight'])

    gs.tight_layout(fig, pad=0)

plot_form_page()

plt.savefig('page.pdf',
            dpi=300,
            orientation='portrait')
```